# MySQL Query Select Distinct Where

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a php script to query my database for products that are marked as deleted, get the image reference number and delete that image. The problem is I have some images that are used by multiple products, only some of which are deleted. So I need a query that will find all unique image number for products that are deleted, but only if they are not also used by NOT deleted products.

Each product has a unquieID, ImageID and Deleted (is null if NOT deleted or contains a 7 or 8 digit number if it is deleted) column.

Here is the query I came up with to fetch the images from deleted products. I am just not sure how to have the query check to see if the product is used by any note deleted products. I would prefer not to have to do a another query for that check because I have over 750000 products in the database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ImageId 
FROM productdata 
WHERE ImageId != 0 
    AND Deleted IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Have you tried this query, Ericlmprint?

Comment: Yes, and it shows all the images that are with delete products, but it will also show images from products that are not deleted as well if the image is used by a product that is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about something like this? Count the total number of images, and count how many times it's been deleted. if the delete count matches the image count, then all instances of the image's products have been deleted.

```
SELECT 
  ImageID, 
  COUNT(ImageID) AS total_images, 
  SUM(Deleted IS not NULL) AS deleted_images
FROM productData
GROUP BY ImageID
HAVING total_images = deleted_images
```

Comment: Nice. I love creative thinking. It worked and relatively fast, only a few seconds slower than my basic query.

Comment: I may be missing something but the query appears not to work in this case: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15229/2 . Does `SUM(ImageID IS NULL)` really work?

Comment: ImageID IS NULL should be DELETED IS NOT NULL
but with that change it works and is FAST.

Comment: @w0lf: mysql will take the boolean value returned by the `is null` test and cast it to an int, so false/0 and true/1.

Comment: @EricImprint OK, now I see how it works. I didn't know MySql supports this syntax. Great solution indeed! +1

Comment: though, I just thought of a glitch in this. count(field) will count non-null values. it'd have to be count(*) to count rows instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this query:

```
SELECT ImageId
FROM productdata 
WHERE ImageId != 0 
GROUP BY ImageId
HAVING sum(CASE WHEN Deleted is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) = 0
```

You can test it online here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15229/2

How it works:

- `GROUP BY ImageId` ensures that we get distinct `ImageId` values
- `sum(CASE WHEN Deleted is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)` is the count of records having a given `ImageId` that are not deleted

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It takes a LONG time compared to Marc's (corrected) on my huge database, but it was nice to have as a check.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ImageId 
FROM productdata pd
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM productdata 
    WHERE pd.ImageId != ImageId AND Deleted IS NOT NULL
) = 0
```

Comment: I let it run for over 45 seconds and it still hadn't worked. Thanks for the idea.